# View semicolon-separated .csv files in gnumeric

Tags: csv, gnumeric

I have a semicolon-separated csv file over here, and I would like to be able to look at it with gnumeric. Sadly, gnumeric does not read the semicolon as a separator.

I have tried:

- appending `sep=;` on the first line
- clicking through the GUI menus
- using sed to replace the semicolons with commas (sadly, that leads to breakage, since by document occasionally uses commas within cells

What else can I do?

Comment: I've voted to put this on hold as off-topic, as I think it's not really about programming; I expect it would be better on _Super User_. I think it might be too old to migrate though. However, I've upvoted it, as it was most helpful - thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In recent versions of `gnumeric` a new `Import Data` tool is available. To launch the tool choose `Data|Import Data|Import Text File...` from the menu.

1. In the `Import Data File` dialog choose your file and hit `Open`.
2. In the next screen select `Separated` format and click `Forward`
3. In the following screen select a separator from a number of available options and click `Forward` once again to choose the columns to import.
4. Click `Finish` to complete.

[image]

Comment: Damn this "Finish" button…

Answer (score -1):

Solution that worked for me in a comma separated csv file with dot decimal separators:

1. Open .csv file from a text editor
2. replace all "," with ";" (semicolon)
3. replace all dot decimal separators "." with ","
4. save file
5. open gnumeric, go to Data -> Get External Data -> Import Text File
   and then open the saved file
6. hit Forward and Finish
7. save as a gnumeric file